# Schedule taks with schtask.exe gives error invalid syntax in script

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, windows-task-scheduler

I want to create a scheduled task using C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe in a perl script. I'm using the following script:

```
use strict;
my $createScheduleTask = `SchTasks /Create /SC WEEKLY /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN \"updater\" /TR \"\\\\network\\shared\\updater.bat\" /ST 19:00`;
```

But I get the following response:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "SCHTASKS /?" for usage.
```

When I run the same command in the CLI it works fine (I did remove the escape '\'-s.)
I've tried about every possible combination of escape characters, but I cannot find out what is wrong.

So does anybody know what is wrong or does anybody know how to debug it?

Thanks
Rudy
PS I don't want to use Win32::TaskScheduler since it is not installed on all clients.

Comment: Your code worked fine at my end. I got the following output: `C:\Users\Chankey\Desktop>perl test.pl
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "updater" has successfully been created.`

Comment: Works here, cut and paste error? Permissions problem?

Comment: Change `my $createScheduleTask = \`...\`;` to `my $cmd = qq\`...\`; my $createScheduleTask = \`$cmd\`;`, so you can print the command you actually ran and find the syntax error.

Comment: Ok, on two other machines the script works fine. So I will be blaming it on 'some' machine configuration. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the shell that you are running the command from.

I had this problem when running from a bash shell, but when I opened a standard Windows command prompt it runs fine.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was trying to run it through Git's bash shell. Running it through the standard CMD shell solved the problem. Thank you!